# How to get the checked items from APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2 in oracle apex5?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How can I pull the checked items in APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2 in oracle apex5?

```
select apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx => 1,
                           p_value => SERVICE_GROUP ,
                           p_attributes => 'class="serviceGrp"',
                           p_checked_values => :P40_STORE,
                           p_checked_values_delimiter => ',') 
         as A,
       SERVICE_GROUP AS "NAME"
  from RESPONSIBLE_GROUPS  
 group by SERVICE_GROUP
```

I am using the above query to display checkbox but my problem is how to get the checked values and store them in a hidden item like `P40_STORE`

Comment: Please use triple quote ``` to signify the markup

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_app.htm#AEAPI215